# PDO prepare() make a valid request fail with variable containing {{}}

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I try to insert some data in a db using the following server side php script :

```
$questionID = htmlentities(filter_var($_GET['questionID'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING), ENT_QUOTES);
$typeVal = htmlentities(filter_var($_GET['typeVal'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING), ENT_QUOTES);
$newVal = htmlentities(filter_var($_GET['newVal'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING), ENT_QUOTES);

    try {
        $query = 'UPDATE `questions` SET `'.$typeVal.'` = ? WHERE `id_question` = ?';
        $res = $con_init->prepare($query);
        $result = $res->execute(array($newVal, $questionID));
    } catch (Exception $e)
    {
        die('Error query: ' . $e->getMessage() . 'code : ' . $e->getCode());
    }

    $message = $typeVal." ".$newVal." ".$typeVal." ".$questionID. " ".$query." ".$con_init->debugDumpParams();

    if ($result == true)
    {
        $return = array('message' => $message);
    }    else
    {
        $return = array('message' => "Fail ".$message);
    }
    echo json_encode($return);
```

The value I want to update will receive the following : `{{yyyyyy}}`

The content of `$message` is :

```
variablelink {{yyyyyy}} variablelink 116 UPDATE `questions` SET `variablelink` = ? WHERE `id_question` = ?
```

I checked the doc but didn't find that I would need to escape { or }

By building the `$message` var I can see that all parameters received by the php are the correct ones.

variablelink is a valid column name.

When I try the SQL query in phpmyadmin it works.

But in this script it's always failing... so I guess it has something to do with the way prepare() is preparing my query...what am I missing here ?

Comment: Your code is prone to sql injection.

Comment: my filters are wrong ?

Comment: They are *HTML* filters, while injection is in your *SQL*.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, could you be more specific ? do you mean because of that : SET `'.$typeVal.'` ?

Comment: yes, it's because you are adding a variable in SQL which is improperly formatted.

Comment: yes but prepared statements do not accept ? for column names. Is there a specific way to filter it ?

Comment: [yes](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#identifiers)

Comment: thanks a lot! very usefull, will implement this right away.
But I still have the problem explained above :/

Comment: Nope, you don't. Neither PDO nor mysql have absolutely nothing to do with contents of your variables. Your problem is caused by something else. If query fails, then there should be an error. You have to read it and fix. Did you set PDO in exception mode?

Comment: I have echoed $con_init->errorCode() but I get 00000

Comment: errorCode() is unreliable source. you have to set PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE  to PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION and get rid of try-catch.

Comment: ok. But then how do I catch the E_WARNING... I am getting only the content of $return (it is an ajax call) so I would need to return the error as a string

Comment: It is not recommended,because internal errors shouldn't be revealed outside as a rule. For a JSON API the proper way would be to send a generalized error message from a site-wide error handler. While actual pdo error have to be logged into error log

Comment: ok. So I checked php_errlog and there is nothing, and $con_init->errorCode() still returns 00000

Comment: Did you set PDO in exception mode? Whatever, there shouldn't be actually any problem with {} braces anyway. Make sure that $result is not overwritten somewhere.

Comment: yes in my constructor : $con_init = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; charset=utf8; dbname=mydbname','myuser','mypass', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));

Comment: it's warning while it have to be exception.

Comment: oh yes, sorry array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION) .... now not any ajax call is working and nothing stated in the php_errlog

Comment: got it now, I have try catch in many functions, got to remove them.... damn php manual!

Comment: finally.... so now I get the issue : Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens'

Comment: There should be a stack trace pointing at the exact query where you miscounted variables.

Comment: yes the line thrown is the query I mentionned just above. Is there a way to return the value of the query which has been executed ?

Comment: anyway I found the issue and now the query execute successfully, but with wrong values, so there is obviously an issue in my parameters transmission.... gonna check that...
Thanks a lot for your help, I have learnt a lot about exception handling and through reading your site about pdo and sql injections

Comment: @YourCommonSense One more question, sorry. I am saving HTML code generated by tinyMCE to my db. Of course I can't filter it the same way as my other variables. Instead, I am using HTMLpurifier with the default setting. Would you consider this a safe acceptable solution ?

Comment: Yes, as far as i know, htmlpurifier is secure enough. However, in your place i would consider using the same markup used here on SO, if possible. It's either secure and very easy to use.

Comment: ok thanks. SO markup is good but I need more advanced features for content formating and I also developped a custom plugin for tinymce so it would be really hell to recode everything for another text editor